# "Input string was not in a correct format." calling int.Parse on a SQL Statement

Tags: c#, sql, rowcount

I am getting the error:

**"Input string was not in a correct format."**

**Note:** If I change line 182 to an actual number in quotes (ie; "3" or "875"), and comment out line 171, *this code works perfectly fine*. However, "{7}", in line 174 is a field that is supposed to auto-increment, but wont. So I am trying to get a "number" in line 171, that will use the number of rows, + 1, to do the auto-=increment.

Any takers on this one?   :-)

```
171   string rowCount = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE Location is NULL");

173   string sql = string.Format("insert into Log values " +
174         "('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},'{4}',#{5}#,'{6}','{7}')",
175         comboBox1.Text,
176         comboBox2.Text,
177         float.Parse(textBox1.Text),
178         float.Parse(comboBox3.Text),
179         textBox3.Text,
180         textBox2.Text,
181         addRemove,
182         int.Parse(rowCount) 
183         );
```

Comment: Again, PLEASE assume in advance, that there is NOTHING wrong with lines 173 through 181, as that part of the code will insert data to my table. I can't help but thinking there has to be a parsing of line 171's resulting data. But I just can't seem to get it.  :-/

Comment: Why are you doing a String.Format (line 171) on a string without actually formatting it?

Comment: You're calling "int.Parse" on an SQL query?  Essentially: int.Parse("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE Location is NULL");  That's causing the problem.  Perhaps you meant to parse the result of the query, not the query itself.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, precisely. How can I parse that?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Maybe that's line 172?  :-)

Comment: Would this not work?     "int rows = (int.Parse(rowCount) + 1);"

Comment: That might increment it as well, no?

Comment: @Geo: well, perhaps you have to _execute_ your SQL, and parse the _output_.

Comment: Naah, you don't parse the result of the query, you just put the exact string rowCount into the string sql. Without apostropes even. So there's the error out of the way. There. Now delete lines 173 through 183 and use parameters.

Comment: I took everything past "Log" out of line 171, BTW,

Comment: @MrLister, I HAVE to have lines 173 through 183, LOL! That's what is passing the data into my fields!  :-)

Comment: Not sure how to put this. Ehm, how about "Don't let me stop your great self destruction."

Comment: @Geo: You really don't have to have those lines. You need *some* code to get your data into the database. It *doesn't* have to be that code.

Comment: How is it self destruction, when I mentioned earlier that the code on all of those lines already works, as long as field {7} isn't involved in the string, or the input is a quoted number?

Comment: @Geo: I bet that code will do interesting things if someone types in a value with a quote. Now would be a very good time to read up on SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @JonSkeet. What would you suggest, to replace it?

Comment: BRB . . . I need a PBJ sammich!

Comment: @Geo: Parameterized SQL, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Stop using that code **immediately** and use parameterized SQL instead. Otherwise you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), as well as potentially having data type conversion issues.

Next, think about what you've actually got in `rowCount`. It isn't a string representing an integer - it's some SQL. Trying to parse that with `int.Parse` isn't going to work, is it?
You'd need to execute the query first - or use a subquery within your insert statement. To be honest, if it's *meant* to be an auto-incrementing field, I would just concentrate on getting that working rather than fudging round it with code which is going to be vulnerable to race conditions.

Comment: @GarethD Don't you think he's got enough points by now? You don't want him to get another of those ugly paintings, would you?

Comment: @JonSkeet, my original intent was to get the auto-increment to work, but it seemed like an act of congress to get it done. I would actually RATHER that. Any good suggestions?
C# program, Access database . . .

Comment: @Geo: Well we don't have any information about how it's set up etc - I suggest you ask that as a separate question (given that changing this question now would make all the existing answers and comments look pretty weird). But even if you get that to work, you really *really* need to stop putting values directly into your SQL.

Answer (score 2):

`int.Parse(rowCount)` converts string to number, e.g. "100500" to 100500. But your string contains `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE Location is NULL"` and this is not a number.

Answer (score 2):

`string.Format` is not going to execute your SQL commands. So `int.Parse` sees exactly `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE Location is NULL"`, which of course is not a decimal representation of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Virtually all databases have native support for auto-incrementing columns.  You should not be trying to use an int column and increment it yourself.  There are all sorts of race conditions, performance issues, etc. to make an incrementing column really robust, and the database designers have already taken care of all of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for an answer that will fix your problems with this particular posting. The answers that have been posted will help you do that.

You should examine other approaches.
Use a command object and use parameters (suggested by @JonSkeet)

Do some research on how auto increment columns work. This varies by database vendor. It appears that you may be using Microsoft Access. For MS Sql Server the auto-increment column is an identity column and in Oracle, the mechanism is a bit different again, using sequences. Basically, you do not supply values for auto-increment columns, you let the database engine handle that for you. (also mentioned by a previous poster)
I would also suggest that you assign the values of your text boxes to variables and do some validation of the data before putting into your insert statements or parameters. Try to program defensively.